# An Integration Services class cannot be found

Tags: ssis

I have written a win forms application that runs a DTSX package.  The package works fine on my machine, but I cannot get it to run on my other machine.  Do I need to have SQL or SSIS installed on that machine too?  If so, SSIS isn't free so would I be able to use my license from my other SQL instance to get SSIS onto this machine?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to install SQL Server Integration Services on each machine that expects to execute an SSIS package.

Yes, that will incur a licensing cost and no, it's not going to be cheap. Feel free to consult your licensing agent to confirm/deny this.

Alternatives to this approach generally boil down to making remote calls to the sql server instance to run the requested package. Whether you create a custom windows/web service on that server, make use of SQL Agent or a TSQL call is really dependent on how you like to solve problems.

Comment: I see, that makes sense as well.  I actually had it setup as a SQL agent job at first, but I thought maybe I was over complicating it.  I also couldn't figure out how to pass variables to it.  Do you think I should go back to that method of doing it?

Comment: Insufficient data to specify whether agent would be appropriate. Since you've stated you need to pass a variable, that strongly suggests agent is not going to be a good fit.